# '.sort' not working on Safari

Tags: jquery, safari

Is working fine on Chrome, could someone tell me why it isn't sorting the table on Safari and how to fix it?
I've looked the console, there's no error.
**HTML:**

```
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="d1" value="01/01/1992">   
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="d1" value="01/01/1991">   
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button>SORT</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    sort();
});

function sort() {
    $('tBody tr').sort(function(a, b) {
        return new Date($(a).find('input[name="d1"]').val()).getTime() > new Date($(b).find('input[name="d1"]').val()).getTime()
    }).appendTo('tBody');
}
```

**JsFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/nm5vbtdq/1/

Comment: What kind of error do you get in Safari?

Comment: It doesn't sort, there's no error on console.

Comment: Have you checked that `new Date(...)` produces the same values for your input strings in all browsers? Unless you're using standard ISO `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` strings, it is quite likely they are not being parsed the same.

Comment: @apsillers I didn't know that, I'm using format mm/dd/yyyy, must be that, I'll search how to convert it.

Comment: You may be interested in the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library, which allows you to specify a format string, rather than relying on implementation-variable support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to return a -1/1 instead of a boolean in Safari, see below:

```
function sort() {
    $('tBody tr').sort(function(a, b) {
        var result = new Date($(a).find('input[name="d1"]').val()).getTime() > new Date($(b).find('input[name="d1"]').val()).getTime() ? 1 : -1;
        return result;
    }).appendTo('tBody');
}
```