# Custom function in function chain - To get Length of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to extract the length of an array while mapping it.

Here is what happens:

First I have an array of objects. Each object has a key of posts where I store the posts for that object. My code takes all the posts from all the objects and maps them to a new array so that I can show all the posts from all the objects to the user on the front end.

I'd like to show only 10 posts at a time. So I put a `.slice(0, page * 10)` - the variable page is controlled by a button at the bottom of the page. If the user hits the button, the page then increases the number of posts on the screen.

This all works great. BUT - I'd like to be able to count the total number of posts and only show the button when there are more posts available. Is there a way to extract the number of posts while still allowing it to map the results from this function below?

```js
{
  bandTypes === "all"
    ? allBands
      .filter(band => {
        if (showType !== 'Show Type') {
          return band.showTypes.includes(showType)
        } else {
          return band
        }
      })
      .reduce(
        (allPosts, band) =>
          allPosts.concat(
            (band.youtube.length > 0 &&
              band.bandBio !== "n/a" &&
              band.bandGenre !== "n/a")
              ? band.posts.map((post) => ({ post, band }))
              : []
          ),
        []
      )
      .sort((a, b) => new Date(b.post.date) - new Date(a.post.date))
      .slice(0, page * 10)
      .map(({ post, band }) => <div key={uuidv4()}>{convertPost(post, band)}</div>)
    : null
}
```

It would be great if I could just put an anonymous function in there somewhere that sets the state to the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think that trying to accomplish this without any temporary variables is not going to be very efficient and probably would be quite ugly.

I think you should first create the array of all posts and then simply use it's `length` inside the `return` of your component.

Here's an example of how I would do it:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    let allPosts = []
    if (bandTypes === "all") {
        allPosts = allBands
            .filter((band) => {
                if (showType !== "Show Type") {
                    return band.showTypes.includes(showType)
                } else {
                    return band
                }
            })
            .reduce(
                (allPosts, band) =>
                    allPosts.concat(
                        band.youtube.length > 0 &&
                            band.bandBio !== "n/a" &&
                            band.bandGenre !== "n/a"
                            ? band.posts.map((post) => ({
                                  post,
                                  band,
                              }))
                            : []
                    ),
                []
            )
            .sort((a, b) => new Date(b.post.date) - new Date(a.post.date))
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {allPosts.slice(0, page * 10).map(({ post, band }) => (
                <div key={uuidv4()}>{convertPost(post, band)}</div>
            ))}
            {allPosts.length < page * 10 && <button>Show more posts</button>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

(BTW using something like `uuidv4` for the `key` isn't ideal, because React is less efficient with rendering then. It's better base the `key` on something that is unique to each post and doesn't change for each render, for example an id from the database or something of this sort)

Comment: Thanks again Adam! I've been away and not able to try it yet, but it makes a lot of sense. - In the mean time... I think that you are right at about UUID loading slow - Does this load slow outside of react too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62314291/foreach-happens-too-fast-with-async-await?noredirect=1#comment110209002_62314291

Comment: The UUID implementation is probably really quick and not really a problem. Just it's best for `keys` to give all components a stable identity, so React knows which ones changed, moved or were removed with fewer computations. Take a look [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) for the most reliable information.

Comment: I see! Thanks man! Man I have learned so much by doing all this! Really appropriate it all!

Comment: Hey Adam! I just got a chance to reformat the code this morning to work with this - Yes! It works great. I also change the react keys to have specific ids found form the posts in the database! I am doing a ton of testing now - Maybe a few last min features to add to the site... But other than that! Wow! I am so impressed with my first site! Thanks for your help, really!

Comment: Hey Adam! Do you know any reason that git or npm run build would exclude images/routes for my application on heroku? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62723427/public-folder-in-heroku-not-working-with-images-and-routes

Comment: Hey Adam! Long time no see! I am having some trouble rendering multiple instances of the same component in some react! Would you have any time to check this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63414947/react-usestate-setstate-error-not-a-function-when-multiple-instances-of-compnen